# Cache Control Working Differently for Different Browsers?

Tags: node.js, http, caching, cache-control

Serving a bunch of images.

I set `Cache-Control: max-age:3000` and specifiy `ETag` in HTTP my response headers.

When the client requests for the same file, I respond with `304` because they are just image files and will be the same.

Perhaps I misunderstood caching, but:

1. Isn't the client only supposed to check for new file after the
   max-age period is complete ?
2. Shouldn't the client have cached the image and display it from cache when it receives `304` from server ?

In Firefox it's doing neither. In Chome, it requests for the file, before the max-age, but when it receives `304` response, it displays the image from cache.

Server is a node server. I can share the relevant code, if you think it would help answer better. Although, at this point I am looking for pointers/hints as to what might have gone wrong.

I m doing something wrong, but can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the syntax wrong; it's "max-age=3000"

Comment: Ty. Corrected that. It still does not work though. Do I need to do something while requesting the resource maybe ? The request headers that goes out to try and fetch the resource again has `cache-control: no-cache`, is that what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTTPS and have an old version of Firefox the problem could be caused by the lack of Cache-Control: public in your response headers. However, this was fixed a few years ago:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=531801

The Cache-Control: no-cache in the request headers indicates a forced refresh in Firefox (e.g. using Ctrl+F5 on Windows). Are you forcing a reload of the page or just revisiting the page in a fresh instance of Firefox?

You can check the state of the image in the Firefox cache by going to 'about:cache' or using a tool like [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com).

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am forcing a reload of the page. Unfortunately I need to do a reset after "one round" of activities is done and if the user wants to go for another round of activities. Although I could do some javascript to go back to original state but `location.reload(true);` is much easier for me to go back to original state for another round of activities. Is that what is confusing firefox ? Chrome does not get effected by force reload tho.